# Shrinking and growing creatures with laptop

Tags: spore, spore-galactic-adventures

When you are making a mission, is it possible to turn creatures into epics and babies in Spore Galactic Adventure even though you don't have a scrolling wheel or if you have a laptop?

Comment: Do you not have a touchpad you can scroll with?

Comment: yes i do have a touch pad

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick look around on [the](http://forum.spore.com/jforum/posts/list/56761.page) [spore](http://forum.spore.com/jforum/posts/list/2748.page) [forums](http://forum.spore.com/jforum/posts/list/52247.page), and it seems there is no way to actually do it without a mouse, which is very strange, since every other feature allows you to use a combination with the arrow keys.

There also doesn't seem to be a mod, and Firaxis doesn't have any plans to patch it (since it's a little dated), so you might be out of luck.

As @MatthewRead was pointing at, if you have a touchpad, you can use that, by holding down shift, then pinching to do the shrinking/growing.